# Select Date(String Date)<DATE(Text Column with Date)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, select

I have a table with a column of the type text where I store various settings, including dates, using `NOW()` in the insert query.

Now I want to get all rows from this table where this column is before a specific date (e.g. 2012-09-19).

Comparing via `DATE(date_column)<DATE(NOW())` is easy, but I don't know how to pass a specific date instead of NOW(), because date formats of the input string may differ.

Here's a sample code:

```
INSERT INTO table (date_column) VALUES (NOW())
```

And when selecting:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date_column)<DATE('2012-09-19');
```

**EDIT: The above code actually works. I was missing the quotes around the date initially.**

Comment: You can add an answer yourself and accept it, so people can see that the question is answered.

Comment: Have a look at the STR_TO_DATE function. but you'll need to use a where clause to limit the rows to those with dates in. Presumably there's a property name column. Hope you've learnt your lesson on this one. Two classic database design errors in one this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid placing functions around your column types (`WHERE FUNCTION(col) ...`). This decreases performance. You want to have a table that has domain integrity, meaning if you are storing a date, it is a `date` type.

To select records that match your `date`, simply encase your YYYY-MM-DD date in quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_column < '2012-09-19'
```

Answer (score 0):

If date_column truly is of type DATE, you don't need to run DATE() on it.

Also note that running DATE() on date_column will prevent MySQL from using any indexes, so you'll be doing a table scan.

Try:

```
WHERE date_column < '2012-09-19'
```